# Query SQL listando lojistas por id e status

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Pessoal tenho uma tabela aonde lista compras de clientes, nessa tabela tenho informação como o id do lojista e o status do pedido, esse status vai de 0 a 6, porém eu gostaria de exibir apenas quando o status estiver até 5, estou tentando dessa forma

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_compras WHERE loja_id="& lojista_id &" OR status=0 OR status=1 OR status=2 OR status=3 OR status=4 OR status=5 ORDER BY status ASC LIMIT 20
```

Porém acabar me retornando todos os resultados de outros lojistas e eu só quero de um lojista especifico.

Aonde estou errando?

Comment: Você precisa encapsular entre parênteses as duas condições.

Comment: O primeiro OR parece estar errado , use o IN < ...loja_id="& lojista_id &" and  status in (1,2,3,4,5) ... >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está selecionando todos que tenham id = $id OU qualquer outro status, faça

```
loja_id = "id do lojista " AND status < 6
```

Erro de lógica, está usando ou em vez de "e"

Se precisar usar vários `OR` como fez, use o parenteses:

```
loja_id = "id do lojista " AND (status = 5 OR status = 4...) //por exemplo
```

Comment: compreendido! obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a clausula
loja_id = "id do lojista " AND status <= 5

Desta forma vai trazer apenas todos os IDS de logidta que vão de 0 até 5
Se quiser fazer um excelente curso de SQL deixo abaixo o link do meu portal de cursos
[www.fpw.com.br/ead](http://www.fpw.com.br/ead)
Lá têm o curso SQL mais completo que você encontra na internet